# Is ninja able to handle long filename?

Tags: ninja

I'm trying to build qt6 in win10 using cmake+ninja. I got the following error:

> ninja: error:
> Stat(qtquickcontrols2/src/imports/controls/fusion/impl/CMakeFiles/qtquickcontrols2fusionstyleimplplugin_resources_qtquickcontrols2fusionstyleimplplugin_qml_files_resource_2.dir/.rcc/qmlcache/qtquickcontrols2fusionstyleimplplugin_qml_files_resource_2/qmlcache_loader.cpp.obj):
> Filename longer than 260 characters

I tried to switch on the long file path in registry, and it doesn't help.
Is ninja able to handle long filename?

Comment: as long as the issue [#1900](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1900) is open, `ninja` can't handle long paths

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug when trying to build Qml static plugins.

The bug report:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88581

If you don't need Qml static plugins, you can build Qt framework without them, by adding these parameters to the configure command:

```
-skip qtdeclarative -skip qtquick1 -skip qtquickcontrols \
-skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qttools -skip qtwebengine
```

Comment: this is a nice workaround, but what to do if you need those modules, especially `qtwebengine`?